Advanced custom fields Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_field()
We are getting this error i think due to the Advanced Custom Fields plugin being deactivated. The problem is we now can not activate it as we can't even access the admin dashbaord.
Any help would be appreciated.
Deactivating plugins and themes

The answer below will get you going, but I strongly recommend wrapping any code you have that calls get_field or the_field in if ( class_exists('ACF') {....} that way if you deactivate ACF, you can avoid this issue. This is speaking from experience and 100s of sites with ACF.

get_field is a function that is now undefined and this function is in use. The simplest solution would be to reactivate the plugin or the library that defines it, but since that's not an option for you, you could implement it in some manner, like
function get_field() {
    return null;
}

or return some other dummy value that suits you. Or, you can decide to implement this method yourself, that is, take a look at how it is implemented in the plugin that defined it, paste it to your end and fix it until it works.
As @disinfor suggested in the comment section, one can wrap a conditional around the definition of the function, so if the plugin is reactivated, then the code will not need urgent changes:
if (!function_exists('get_field')) {
    //Your custom definition here...
}


May consider also wrapping that in a if ( ! function_exists('get_field') so when the OP activates ACF again, it won't throw a function already defined error.

@disinfor thanks for the suggestion, I have edited my answer accordingly.
